# Isomorphism between a quotient space and a subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, quotient-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism, unbounded-operators

When $L$ is an unbounded operator on a Hibert space $H$, and $K = Ker  L$,  $H/ K \simeq K^\perp$?

I'd appreciate it if you'd give me any help! Thank you.

**I've added the source below.

[image]

Comment: If $L$ is an unbounded operator how do define $H/K$? Ker (L) need not be closed.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Thank you for responding to me. That's why I am asking this. This is from Cedric Villani's book and I've added that part of the book.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed $H/K$ may not be defined when  $L$ is not bounded.

For any close subspace $K$ of $H$ we always have $H/K$ isometrically isomorphic to $K^{\perp}$. To get an  isometrically isomorphism write any element $h$ uniqely as $h_1+h_2$ with $h_1 \in K$ and $h_2 \in K^{\perp}$. Verify that the map $h+K \to h_2$ is an isometric isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you. I've added the source to my original post. There, Villani says $L$ is an unbounded operator and in the middle, he says "The most standard way is when $K^{\perp} \simeq H/ K$. Do you think I am missing something?

Comment: Yes, there are other assumptions in that link.

Comment: What assumptions make $H/K$ well defined and isomorphic to $K^{\perp}$? Could you elaborate a little bit more  please?

Comment: If $L$ is a bounded operator then the kernel $K$  is a closed subspace. So the answer to  your second question is YES, as indicated in my answer.

Comment: Yes, if $L$ is bounded, I understand you. However, in the source I posted, $L$ is unbounded. Is there any statement that makes $L$ a bounded operator?